# Word user VBA set to Textbox border style

Tags: vba, ms-word

The text box is added in MS Word using the vba function `...Shapes.AddTextbox(...)`. How do I set the border style of the created Textbox to dots using vba?

I did tried to record a macro while setting the line style manually but the code did not appear in the macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Sub InsertTextBox()
  Dim tb As Shape
  Set tb = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox _
    (Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
    Left:=1, Top:=1, Width:=100, Height:=100)
  tb.Line.DashStyle = msoLineRoundDot
End Sub
```